# UISearchBar displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar

Tags: ios7, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar, uisearchbardisplaycontrol

I want to replicate the functionality of the Twitter app where the search bar slides in to the navigation bar.

However I have run into a problem. If I don't add

```
[self.searchDisplayController setDisplaysSearchBarInNavigationBar:YES];
```

into viewDidLoad the bar will not appear. I have a search button in the righthand navigation item when I click it I call the above method. Is there anything I can do to ensure the search bar gets drawn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add search bar on navigation bar....

initially in your viewDidLoad:-

```
mySearchBar.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, -80.0, 320.0, 44.0);
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:mySearchBar];
```

in your action method

```
mySearchBar.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0, 320, 44);
```

in viewWillDisappear

```
[mySearchBar removeFromSuperview];
```