# Search bar expand from Search button on iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

How can I make my search bar expand in the navigation bar when I click the search button, like the one in the Twitter app? Right now my search bar just comes down over the top of the navigation bar. This is the function that I call when I click on the search button in the navigation bar:

```
func searchbuttonclicked(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    var searchresults = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("searchresults") as searchResultsController

    var searchcontroller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: searchresults)
    searchcontroller.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    searchcontroller.searchResultsUpdater = searchresults
    searchcontroller.modalTransitionStyle = .CrossDissolve

    presentViewController(searchcontroller, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22576803/uisearchbar-displayssearchbarinnavigationbar), you can use something like:

```
// declare as property
var searchBar: UISearchBar!

// in viewDidLoad
searchBar = UISearchBar(frame: CGRectMake(0.0, -80.0, 320.0, 44.0))
navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(searchBar)

// in action to show
searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0, 320, 44)

// in viewWillDisappear
searchBar.removeFromSuperview()
```

However, the `searchBar` property on `UISearchController` is read-only, so you'll need to subclass `UISearchController` to make it use the search bar in the navigation controller instead of the one it presents by default.